# C++ MapiMessageW will not open mail client if recipients are assigned

Tags: c++, windows, email, mapi

I have a working method which will successfully open Outlook (and other mail clients), open a new message window, and set the body and subject fields with provided strings, and attach one or more files indicated by a vector of our internal filepath object. I'm trying to extend this to add a recipient in the To: field. The code below omits all of the subject/body/path stuff for brevity and just shows what I've done with recipients.

```
void createMailMessage( const char *recipientAddr, const char *subject, const char *body, const std::vector<FSPath> &attachments) {
  // first get all of the const char* into std::wstring 
  // ommitted here for brevity

  MapiMessageW message = { 0 };
  MapiRecipDescW *recipients = NULL;
  if (recipientAddr != NULL) {
    recipients = new MapiRecipDescW[1];
    memset(recipients, 0x00, sizeof(MapiRecipDescW) ) // only one recipient
    recipients[0].lpszAddress = (PWSTR) recipStrW.c_str(); // recipStrW is from omitted code above
    recipients[0].ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
    message.nRecipCount = (ULONG) 1;
    message.lpRecips = recipients;
  }

  // fill in the rest of the message info here
  // this stuff is already working and i left it unchanged

  MAPISendMailHelper(NULL, NULL, &message, MAPI_LOGON_UI|MAPI_DIALOG, 0);
}
```

In the debugger I can see that the message struct is still well-formed, simply with the addition of a pointer to the recipients struct and the nRecipCount field filled correctly. That struct is also well-formed, with the expected address string and class value. When the code executes, it reaches the same call that produces the new message dialog ( pfnMapiSendMailA() in MapiUnicodeHelp.h ), but does not seem to execute it.

Help! What am I missing?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you type-casting `recipStrW.c_str()`?  What is `recipStrW` declared as? `recipientAddr` is a `char*`, so I assume that `recipStrW` is a `std::wstring` or similar class type that `recipientAddr` is being converted to, yes? You should not type-cast, let the compiler complain if `c_str()` returns the wrong data type. Does `recipStrW` stay in scope an keep the recipient data alive in memory until after `MAPISendMailHelper()` has exited? What error code does `MAPISendMailHelper()` return when it fails to open the email window? Why is `pfnMapiSendMailA()` being called with Unicode data?

Comment: Your question about `pfnMapiSendMailA()` caused me to do some digging, I realized that the `mapi32.dll` file must be incorrect because it wasn't finding any of the procs in it. Downloaded the Win8 SDK (I'm on 7) and now I'm getting a different error. It successfully finds the right proc with the mapi provider, but the sendmail call returns errcode `2: One or more unspecified errors occurred. No message was sent.` Progress, but now I'm stumped again :(

Comment: @RemyLebeau also the fields on the message struct and on the recipient struct both look fine in the debugger with the typecast, and the data is not freed all the way down to when the proc from the .dll is called with it. The address field on the recipient is of the form `L"SMTP:me@example.com"`